# List of Weirding Words for the Weirding Module in Dune?

Tags: dune, dune-1984

Is there a comprehensive list of Weirding words to be used with the Weirding Module in the Dune universe? There are several obviously pronounced in the original movie. In the movie, Mua-Dib is a 'killing' word, but I couldn't actually find a list of these words anywhere. I'm interested in both cannon and non-cannon words.

Comment: As far as I know, the whole Weirding Module thing only appears in the David Lynch movie. It’s definetely not in the novel nor the TV adaption. I do not know, however, about video games etc.

Comment: Well I suppose I could put together a list myself from the film. Really surprised that nobody has anything put together.

Comment: @ouflak - possibly because a lot of fans of the series would rather forget the movie ever existed.  Shame really, I love David Lynch and the movie looked so great too - but the story was awful.

Comment: :-) I'm getting that sense! I'll probably go through the wish-were-forgotten movie and post a list of the words I can cull out of it myself later on.

Comment: Also, if I recall correctly, apart from *Mua'dib,* the only “words” used in the movie were not really words, but rather shouts and grunts.

Comment: I'm going to get the movie out when I get the next chance, or maybe just Youtube the relevant scenes, but I'm 'fairly' certain he does refer to the sounds specifically as 'words' though that may have simply been convenient nomenclature. I mean, what else would you call them?

Comment: Dude, it's obviously scientific. It's all based on Teals's discoveries of frequencies and vibrations in the realm of electromagnetics!

Comment: Sorry, Tesla's discoveries .

Comment: When weirding extras in bit weirding parts of weirding films need to give the background effect of conversing, they say “rhubarb.” Within the Weirding Way, any viewers instantly believe some sort of real conversation is taking place.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are no canon words, because the whole idea is non-canon. Although you mention the novel, this concept is unequivocally not present in any of the novels.

In the books, "the Weirding Way" is a phrase the Fremen use to describe the superlative physical and mental training developed by the Bene Gesserit. It has nothing at all to do with sonic weapons.

Comment: So no list then of even the non-cannon words? So be it. Thanks.

Comment: No lists in Scifi.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Envite - as much as I have no interest in a list of weirding module words, this isn't a list in the "list of movies with ray guns in them" sense, its a definitive and defined set of words used in one movie, and as such is a perfectly good question/answer.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only words seen in the film are "muad'dib" and "Kaaaaaaaaa-Ja"

Comment: There's a third when Paul finishes Feyd. Here the caption says Cha-aksa: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoPKajvq3gE

Comment: My last comment is just an instance of "Kaaa-Ja" as mentioned by Richard. There's still a third, though, when Paul tests the weirding module on Caladan, something like "mmmmm-mopf": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rp_krZRLKo

Answer (score 5):

In the novel, the closest thing to word weaponry can be found listed in the "Terminology of the Imperium" section at the end of the book:

"UROSHNOR: One of several sounds empty of general meaning and which Bene Gesserit implant within the psyches of selected victims for purposes of control.  The sensitized person, hearing the sound, is temporarily immobilized."

Sound design is central to David Lynch's films.  With Dune, he used the interior voice-over to tremendous effect (that trick usually never works), he used distortion etc with The Voice, and he invented the sound weaponry element.  Non-canonical, but brilliant.

Comment: Good find! +1 I will put the list up once I've overcome my natural procrastinative abilities.

Comment: He did do a good job with the voice itself. But no, the sound weapon was dumb and unbrilliant.  Not just because its not canon but because .. very unscientific.